# Macbook keeps ejecting OSX install disks

Tags: macos, eject

I have this [15 inch Macbook Pro](http://eshop.macsales.com/Descriptions/specs/Framework.cfm?page=mbpmid07.html) (Mid 2007) with OSX Tiger 10.4.11.

I am trying to upgrade OSX to Snow Leopard (10.6) but all CDs and DVDs keep getting ejected without my doing anything.

How can I prevent this automatic ejection of install discs?

Comment: Do other non-install discs get ejected automatically too?

Comment: Does this happen also immediately after a full reboot?

Answer (score 1):

Often this happens when the disc needs cleaning. Soft cotton cloth, warm water, a little dishwashing liquid ... gently, gently ... rinse ... dry softly with aforementioned cloth, not in circular fashion but from center of disc towards outer edge, turning disc as you go.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a great guide for [troubleshooting a laptop optical drive](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2801).  If it's ejecting all discs, you should reset the SMC (and instructions are in the Apple guide above).  If that doesn't work and it's ejecting all discs that you put into it, it's likely that the drive has failed, and you'll need to replace it.  The site that you linked gives instructions for how to do it, and it's not all that hard if you're comfortable taking your laptop apart.

If it's only ejecting some discs and not others, then it's possible that you've got a software or OS issue.  Given that you're trying to upgrade the OS, this might actually solve your problem.  If you have access to another Mac, your best bet is to create a [USB drive with the Snow Leopard installer on it](http://www.maciverse.com/install-os-x-snow-leopard-from-usb-flash-drive.html).

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this in the past as well but with discs originally supplied by a specific model (e.g. iMac). Retail of family install-discs in that case could do the job.